# GIT - Merge an existing local copy with cloned copy

Tags: git

Here is what happened. My friend created a project and handed it to me. I created the repo and started work on the project. He also started working on the project before I was able to get him setup with git so all changes he made are independent of git. Is there any way he can merge his changes into the existing repo?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the two repositories: `base` being the one you worked on and `cloned` being the one that is independent of git. Assuming you have some remote server to collaborate together on these branches, the simplest way would be initializing git on `cloned` and merging that new git repo into your `base` repo (works the same as if they were two branches in one repo).

On `cloned`:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin [url-to-remote]
git push origin master
```

On `base`:

```
git remote add cloned [url-to-remote]
git fetch cloned
git merge cloned/master
# resolve any conflicts and commit if necessary
```

*the preceding steps assumed you were just working on a singular `master` branch*

Comment: it failed when trying to git push origin master

Comment: You'll need to replace `[url-to-remote]`. The easiest way to set up a remote server for git collaboration is with GitHub, [see this document](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote).

Answer (score 0):

He could do this:

1. clone your repository into a new directory
2. create a new branch off the initial commit and switch to it
3. copy his changes into the working directory of his clone
4. commit the changes

At that stage he'll be in the state he would have been in had he been developing in Git from the start and can merge the branch back into `master`, etc.